# Disable WerFault.exe on crashes for specific processes on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-error-reporting

Is it possible to have `werfault.exe` *not* run when specific executables crash? I'm developing some software and (yes I know, it's hard to believe) it occasionally crashes (on purpose) and each time this happens it takes a few seconds for `werfault.exe` to do whatever it wants.

It seems I can turn off the whole service that supports this feature, but I'm happy for it to run on other parts of the system.

So can I tell it to not worry about a certain subset of executables?

**EDIT** As requested by @Moab, here was my research:

- Google for "disable werfault.exe for specific processes windows 10" and a few variations.
- Wade through several pages of results.
- Conclude that this information is not readily available, or I don't know the correct terminology to search for it.
- Realise that there's an opportunity to capture this on Stack Exchange as a canonical example of the problem, helping me and others.
- Think a little more about how to phrase the problem.
- Consider whether to ask on Stack Overflow, Super User or Server Fault.
- Choose Super User seeing as this is likely a desktop computer administration issue, not a server one.
- Head over, ask question.
- Get useful answer quickly. Thank author, vote and accept answer.
- Provide some more relevant information about a useful API I discovered for this in a comment on the accepted answer.
- Later, scratch head at why someone objects so strongly to my question.
- Spend time wondering whether I could really have offered some extra information to the question to help.
- Figure there's nothing to do but try it, so here it is.

**EDIT 2** Actually the above steps are now redundant. This question is now the number one result on Google for my original search terms. I figure this achieves the fourth point from above.

Comment: This is not a Question and Answer forum, What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Comment: @Moab, according to superuser.com: "Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users." Perhaps they have different rules to Stack Overflow ([where I am a long time user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/24874/drew-noakes)) but the only requirement there is to have a question that has a definitive answer. Personally I find questions that are filled with too much description are hard to decipher. Instead I just got to the point. I don't understand how downvoting and adding condescending comments contributes positively to this community, but whatever.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the vote up arrow it will say "this question shows research effort, it is useful and clear" I don't make the rules here. This is how we are different than a Q&A forum.

Comment: I guess you missed this part also..http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Moab, is that more of what you had in mind? Is that honestly a better question?

Comment: Being honest, Its a damn fine question now. Better questions get better faster answers most of the time here on SU.

Comment: It got a great answer before it was vandalised with a wall of useless nonsense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are experiencing Windows Error Reporting (which can be nice sometimes). You can absolutely configure it to not run for certain applications.

The MSDN page [WER Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638.aspx), documents that you can configure **Windows Error Reporting** for the entire machine or per user:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
```

Open regedit and add the following as a REG_SZ (a string value). You might have to add the `ExcludedApplications` key as well:

```
ExcludedApplications\[Application Name]
```

> **Note:** MSDN documents that you should use the [WerAddExcludedApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513617.aspx) function, rather than manually adding items to the **Windows Error Reporting** registry key, to have the excluded.

I would use this if you want to create a .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\ExcludedApplications]
"YourAppName.exe"=""
```

Comment: My answer is right, you reposted the SAME reg snipped what I already posted. Sorry, this is a -1

Comment: You're setting the string to a dword, which may work, but doesn't really make sense to me. Also -- my answer was primarily to provide sources and some more context. I'm not going to argue that it's very similar, but if you go into regedit, follow the instructions to create the `ExcludedApplications` key, and then export it, you do not see a dword:00000001.

Comment: @magicandre1981 your answer was helpful, but this answer provided much more detail and was ultimately more useful. Thanks to you both.

Comment: There is a windows 10 app that is excluded but still causes werfault.exe to run when it crashes. The above procedure didn't work. Ideas?

Comment: I just used WerAddExcludedApplication to add a per-user exclusion to HKCU, and it actually did write a REG_DWORD with a value of 1 into the registry, like @magicandre1981's example. I did not try the parameter to write to HKLM because I don't want to mess with elevation, but I don't imagine it would function any differently. This is on Server 2012 R2. It's possible that the function exists as a wrapper to write the value to the registry because different OS versions could use different registry keys for the config options. But I doubt it.

Answer (score 6):

Copy this into a .reg file and import it by doing a double click on it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\ExcludedApplications]
"MyApp.exe"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. Is there a reference for this? I'd like to use a wildcard if possible.

Comment: In the end I found I could do this programmatically via the [`WerAddExcludedApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513617.aspx) API. I guess it writes into this location on the registry.

Comment: hm, I have no idea if both ways work the same, but nice to hear that you fixed it.